# Can someone explain how LinkedList is used here?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and I want to know how `LinkedList` is used here.

```
public LinkedList<nameofclass> getsomething(String a, int L)
```

Here's the code:

```
public LinkedList<Save> getBrightness( 
    String params, 
    Integer colors, 
    Integer[] BrightnessValue, 
    boolean clear) 
{ 
    ...
    LinkedList<Save> equal = new LinkedList<Save>();
```

Save is a class which is located outside I don't understand this code

Comment: You need to add something more to get more valuable input..

Comment: I'm an old programmer and I don't see enough code here to say how the LinkedList is used.

Comment: `LinkedList` is the return type of this function. It contains instances of `nameofclass`.

Comment: OK ow do we fill in all the mysterious blanks . That's a very challenge my frieeend

Comment: You might need to be more specific. Its a method signature. This method will return LinkedList of type nameOfClass (Which should be Camel case by the way.)

Comment: That's a function called `getsomething` that takes two arguments and returns an instance of `LinkedList<nameofclass>`.

Comment: If you're confused about `<nameofclass>`, google "java generics".

Comment: Ok here the code:

public LinkedList<Save> getBrightness(
            String params,
            Integer colors,
            Integer[] BrightnessValue,
            boolean clear) {
...
...
        LinkedList<Save> equal = new LinkedList<Save>();

Save is a class which is located outside I don't understand this code

Thank you

Comment: Please do not post code in comments; update your post instead. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getBrightness` is creating an instance of `LinkedList` that will contain instances of class `Save`.  Presumably later in the code you will find a loop containing

```
Save s = new Save(...);
s.set...(...);  // maybe
...
equal.add(s);
```

which will create multiple instances of `Save` and add them to the list.  At the end will be

```
return equal;
```

The linked list is being used as a container so that `getBrightness` can return several values.